# Permission denied to run my project locally Zend Framework

Tags: php, linux, xampp, lampp

Well I have just switched to linux and i am having everything setup installed xampp installed every tool but when i try to run my project on localhost it gives an error and app does not open
[image]

I have tried to give access to my htdocs folder using this cammand  but it still not working

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

please help if someone have any idea
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my MONOLOG_PATH which was not correct in application.ini file
the corrected path for me is

> /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/logs/

Answer (score 1):

Your monolog set-up is pointing to `/var/www` and your install is at '/opt/lampp/htdocs'. The install is trying to set-up logging in the wrong place.

You would need to change the monolog setup to point to `/opt/lampp/htdocs'.

By the way, having a public facing web site with permissions at 777 is a security risk. I recommend you do either

```
 sudo chmod 775 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

or depending on your setup

```
 sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

More info at [guide to linux file permissions](https://dev.to/k_penguin_sato/understanding-linux-permissions-397e)

Comment: /opt/lampp/htdocs$ sudo mkdir /var/www/logs: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/logs’: No such file or directory

Comment: i dont really know what 777 permissions do as i said i am new just switched from windows and it was not that much complicated at windows

Comment: Answer edited. 777 means anyone can read, write or execute a program. You don't want that for your web site. "Anyone" could be a hacker!

Comment: ok beyond that permissions part how can i change setup of monolog?